# How to enable tor connection to a local address

Tags: ubuntu, tor

I am running python script using torrify. But tor prevents this script accessing my local address. Any idea how to enable tor to connect to local address?

error:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:4000... 1472701685 WARNING torsocks[3388]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect.c:192)
failed: Operation not permitted.
Retrying.
```

Comment: What command is it running or script of python code?

Comment: I don't know what. But the script runs well without torify.

Comment: Maybe you want to be setting up a hidden service to point to your local service?  Tor will not route onion connections to local addresses unless they're published as a hidden service.  What is the point in connecting to a local port from the local machine over Tor when you can just connect directly?

Comment: The script that I run connects to another another address while it also make connection to local address.

Comment: You can't run it through Torify then.  Instead maybe the configure your code to use Tor's SOCKS proxy for the connection you want to go over Tor?